# Quarkus project build failing in Bamboo

Tags: java, maven, bamboo, quarkus

I'm trying to build a Quarkus app in Bamboo and it's failing with a lot of provisioning errors:

```
[WARNING] Error injecting: io.quarkus.maven.BuildMojo
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting: private org.eclipse.aether.spi.log.Logger 
   org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionRangeResolver.logger
   while locating org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionRangeResolver
   while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
     at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
   while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.VersionRangeResolver
     for parameter 1 at 
   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.<init>(Unknown Source)
   while locating org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem
   while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
   while locating io.quarkus.maven.BuildMojo

   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set 
     org.eclipse.aether.spi.log.Logger field 
     org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionRangeResolver.logger to 
     org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.slf4j.Slf4jLoggerFactory
```

Using Maven 3.2.5 with `clean package` as the goal. The project builds fine locally.

What could be causing this?

Comment: What is "3.x" exactly and can you try 3.5? I suspect the Quarkus Maven plugin requires a certain minimum Maven version, which isn't exactly 3.0.0, but something like 3.3.9 or so.

Comment: Bamboo has the option to choose 3.x and then it uses the latest available. When it builds it's actually using 3.2.5. I will see if that can be upgraded.

Comment: @Ladicek you're right - older versions of maven give the same error locally.

Comment: I added a real asnwer instead of just a comment :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by too old Maven version. Per https://quarkus.io/get-started/, Maven 3.5.3 or later is required.

Comment: Since people still seem to be coming to this answer, I'll point out that the current requirement is Maven 3.6.2 (but 3.6.3 is even better :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

Another reason is that your dependencies are not downloaded. Try to use default `settings.xml` and proxy to download dependencies with proxy.